# Mysql indexing for lengthy query

Tags: mysql, indexing

How can I index below query:

```
SELECT htl_booking_detail.date_add as 'Booking_Date' ,order_invoice.id_order as Donation_No ,htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name as Guest_House_Name, order_invoice.total_paid_tax_incl as Donation, order_state_lang.name as 'Payment Status', 
      (SELECT order_cart_rule.name from order_cart_rule where  (orders.id_order=order_cart_rule.id_order)) as Comment
FROM htl_booking_detail ,htl_room_information,order_invoice,address,orders,htl_branch_info_lang,order_state,order_state_lang, order_cart_rule
WHERE (orders.id_customer=address.id_customer) 
    and (htl_room_information.id=htl_booking_detail.id_room) 
    and (orders.current_state=order_state_lang.id_order_state)
    and (order_invoice.id_order=htl_booking_detail.id_order) 
    and (orders.id_order=order_invoice.id_order)
    and (htl_booking_detail.id_hotel=htl_branch_info_lang.id) 
    and (orders.invoice_number=order_invoice.number) 
    and {{date_add}} 
group by order_invoice.id_order desc;
```

The query display the invoice details as below. But the issue I have experienced is hotel name is in different table 'htl_branch_info_lang'.
The query takes nearly 19 to more minutes to display result.

screenhost at https://ibb.co/PCfV6mJ

Comment: Please add an Explain plan. Also 1) I would amend all the implicit(comma joins) with explicit joins 2) why the group by but no aggregation functions?

Comment: edited above question with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing joining conditions for `order_cart_rule` and `order_state`, so you're computing a full cross-product with those tables. And since you're joining with that table, you don't need the subquery to get `order_cart_rule.name`. You should use `LEFT JOIN` with that table if there might be no matching row, then you'll get `NULL` for the `Comment`.

I'm not sure why you have `order_state` in the list of tables at all, as you don't seem to be using it for anything.

You should also use explicit joins instead of cross-products. If you do this, it will be more obvious when you forget a join condition.

```
SELECT htl_booking_detail.date_add as 'Booking_Date' ,
        order_invoice.id_order as Donation_No ,
        htl_branch_info_lang.hotel_name as Guest_House_Name, 
        order_invoice.total_paid_tax_incl as Donation, 
        order_state_lang.name as 'Payment Status', 
        order_cart_rule.name as Comment
FROM htl_booking_detail 
JOIN htl_room_information ON htl_room_information.id=htl_booking_detail.id_room
JOIN order_invoice ON order_invoice.id_order=htl_booking_detail.id_order
JOIN orders ON orders.id_order=order_invoice.id_order AND orders.invoice_number=order_invoice.number
JOIN address ON orders.id_customer=address.id_customer
JOIN htl_branch_info_lang ON htl_booking_detail.id_hotel=htl_branch_info_lang.id
-- JOIN order_state ON ???
JOIN order_state_lang ON orders.current_state=order_state_lang.id_order_state
LEFT JOIN order_cart_rule ON orders.id_order=order_cart_rule.id_order
WHERE {{date_add}} 
group by order_invoice.id_order desc;
```

Comment: order_state is my wrong. there is no such table. But I tried with above query it displayed only 189 results. my database having 15K entries. please help me on this

Comment: Are you sure all the entries have matches in the other tables? And what is `{{date_add}}`?

Comment: yes matched the entries. but the thing is  it only display the result when any comment in the table order_cart_rule.name. If its null the query above wont display i think. so only display 189 lines of data showing.    date_add is invoice date, which is in table 'order_invoice'. I have taken as {{date_add}}  since I am using metabase to get result. this will help me to get the data of any day.

Comment: If there's might be no matching row in `order_cart_rule` you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: order_cart_rule   having only 194 lines. if any comment added on it, then only this table is going to insert with data. can you help on to get correct data

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use `LEFT JOIN` so it will work when there isn't a row in `order_cart_rule`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got  result. Some 20 lines missing out of 15K. I will look on to it.

Comment: I got the point. if some room numbers are missing and some data is half filled in tables causing this data issue.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` with any table that might have missing data.

Comment: Good answer, but the question was about indexing -- need to add `INDEX(date_add)`

Comment: @RickJames I think it's an XY problem. They asked about indexing, but I felt the actual problem was something else.

Comment: the answer is correct one and it works perfectly for me. before my query was running slow since incorrect joining it looks so I asked for indexing. The above query resolved my issue perfectly.